# Get error from my android login using php

Tags: php, android

i rececntly learn about android and now i'm trying a simple login with my php. Please check my script first

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    final Context context = this;
    private Button button;
    private EditText username;
    private EditText passsword;

    ProgressDialog progress;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void GoLogin(View v){

        username   = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.input_email);
        passsword   = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.input_password);

        String usernameval =  username.getText().toString();
        String passswordval =  md5(passsword.getText().toString());
        new AsyncLogin().execute(usernameval,passswordval);
    }


    private class AsyncLogin extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        ProgressDialog pdLoading = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        HttpURLConnection conn;
        URL url = null;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            pdLoading.setMessage("\tLoading...");
            pdLoading.setCancelable(false);
            pdLoading.show();

        }
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            try {

                url = new URL("http://127.0.0.1:84/fppb/Andro_login");

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return "exception";
            }
            try {
                conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
                conn.setConnectTimeout(10000);
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");


                conn.setDoInput(true);
                conn.setDoOutput(true);

                Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder()
                        .appendQueryParameter("username", params[0])
                        .appendQueryParameter("password", params[1]);
                String query = builder.build().getEncodedQuery();

                OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                        new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
                writer.write(query);
                writer.flush();
                writer.close();
                os.close();
                conn.connect();

            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
                return "exception";
            }

            try {

                int response_code = conn.getResponseCode();

                if (response_code == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

                    InputStream input = conn.getInputStream();
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
                    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
                    String line;

                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        result.append(line);
                    }

                    // Pass data to onPostExecute method
                    return(result.toString());

                }else{

                    return("unsuccessful");
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return "exception";
            } finally {
                conn.disconnect();
            }


        }
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {


            pdLoading.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            if(result.equalsIgnoreCase("true"))
            {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Login success", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }else if (result.equalsIgnoreCase("false")){


                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Invalid email or password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            } else if (result.equalsIgnoreCase("exception") || result.equalsIgnoreCase("unsuccessful")) {

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Cannot connect to main server", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        }
    }

}
```

this is my `androidmanifest.xml`

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"
```

when i try to run my app, i get this error

> "Cannot connect to main server"

in my toast message after i submit at my form. How can i fix this ? thanks in advance ? sorry bad english

reference `http://androidcss.com/android/android-php-mysql-login-tutorial/`

after i read my log(s), i see this

```
W/System.err: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to /127.0.0.1 (port 84) from /10.0.2.15 (port 51319) after 10000ms
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html, you need the `android.permission.INTERNET` permission as well, i.e.,

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Also, you will need to put the IP of your computer on the network into the script - 127.0.0.1 is the loopback IP (it connects to the computer it is running on), so since the server isn't running on your phone, it's not able to find the server.

Comment: i already add <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />, but still error.

Comment: so i need change to my real ip ? do i need to use my port ? because my apache using specified port

Comment: you need the local ip if you are in the same network , please first try to reach the ip from the browser of you device.

Answer (score 2):

**Connect the server and mobile on the same network** or host the server in web server.

Use server system's `IP Address` instead of `127.0.0.1`.

Use IP `10.0.2.2` if you are using an `Emulator`.

**Every system itself is a localhost so when you call 127.0.0.1 the system calls itself.**

**ALSO ADD `INTERNET PERMISSIONS`**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Make sure that you had put your Server `Online` too via `Put Online` from menu tray

Answer (score 0):

Please add permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

in your manifest file where you have declared other permissions